# 3D space of a 4D sphere

Tags: area, volume

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball
Here it says that the 4D Space of a 4D sphere is equal to
$\pi^2R^4/2$.
Does that mean that the 3D space equals
$2\pi^2R^3$?

Comment: That is the volume of the boundary, yes.

Comment: Thanks!! I saw you edit the question to more formalized manner,How did you do that?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference